# Using Qt 4 vs Qt 5 to develop application for Windows and OS X?

Tags: windows, macos, qt, cross-platform

I am considering using Qt to port a standalone Windows application to OS X and possibly Linux. I have never used Qt before. I do not know if I should work with Qt 4 or Qt 5.

I would be interested to get the feedback of developers of fairly large applications using Qt 4 and 5. What are the pros/cons for each version?

More info about the project:

The application is a high end tool for digital photography: real time HDR, Tone Mapping, etc, of large photos at 96-bits per pixel.

The application is currently using the following technologies:

- UI code : C#, C++/CLI, .NET 2.0 WinForm
- Core algorithms: C++, OpenMP, SSE

I plan to use the Qt framework to redevelop the UI code. I have the following constraints:

- Supported OS: Windows XP, Vista, 7 and 8; OS X; (Linux)
- Two builds: 32 and 64-bit
- Application must be able to run on VMs (with little or no OpenGL support)
- Execution speed / real time aspects are essential
- Main development environment: Visual Studio on Windows 7 64-bit

Thanks!

Comment: Trust me, both are perfectly fine. However, would you prefer to stick with the bleeding-edge library, wouldn't you? Then the choice is obvious.

Comment: @Will: Why "closed as not constructive"? I think that my question is quite specific. I have precisely listed the project constraints. I believe there are factual reasons for using Qt 4 over Qt 5 or the reverse in the context of the question. By closing, you are blocking experienced users to share interesting knowledge.

Comment: @user2331479: We actively discourage "subjective" questions.  The ethos behind it can be found in [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/).  Its hard to do, unfortunately.  Your question, asking for feedback and pros/cons, doesn't exactly fit this mold.  Note the answer selected as correct.  It's pretty much just some links, and not much else.  Your question was flagged because of this, and I agreed.  If you believe you can [edit] your question using the blog as a guide, do so and flag to have it reopened.  And for more info, visit [meta].

Comment: It would have been appropriate to close this **before** it received answers, but now that it has it should be open to fully preserve the contributions which have been made.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based just on your platform constraints you probably want to use Qt 5. Windows 7 64-bit is a tier 1 platform in Qt 5. Windows 8 isn't even a tier 2 platform in Qt 4. [Qt 5 has better support for High DPI displays](https://www.qt.io/blog/2013/04/25/retina-display-support-for-mac-os-ios-and-x11) (important to Mac users with Retina displays).

- [Qt 4 Supported Platforms](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/supported-platforms.html)
- [Qt 5 Supported Platforms](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/supported-platforms.html)

Comment: Qt 5 link no longer available

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to avoid OpenGL then Qt 5 isn't going to be a good fit as they moved towards using it as a dependency for QML widgets and the scene graph. That's not to say you can't use it at all, but it's certainly something to consider if you've got an aversion to OpenGL.

Qt 4.8 is perfectly mature, the code base is pretty well covered at this stage, so might be a better fit as the drawing libraries aren't coupled onto OpenGL.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.I will not use GL for the UI. My understanding is that I can still use regular Qt Widgets in Qt 5, right? If yes, does Qt 5 brings other benefits outside of Qt Quick / QML 2? Or maybe it does not make sense to use QT WIdgets in Qt 5?

Comment: You can avoid OpenGL if you're using stock widgets, however a lot of the UI improvements are from the QML/Qt Quick world. There's definitely improvements in a number of core areas, so it's worth looking at the list here: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/qt5-intro.html and make a decision from there.

Answer (score 0):

While the change in version number from 4 to 5 denotes a major release and additional functionality which you may or may not need, there are likely to be bug fixes in 5 that could be of interest to you. Therefore, if you're thinking of going with 4, take a look at the change lists and bug fixes in 5 before making that final decision.